# Mediawiki template url to anchor in other page

Tags: mediawiki

I have a template with the following:

```
[[{{{Target}}}|{{{Name}}}]]
```

If called with `{{tmpl|Target=Hest|Name=X}}` I get a nice link to [X](https://Hest) as expected, if I call with `{{tmpl|Target=Hest#here|Name=X}}` I get "[[Hest#here|X]]", ie the text and no link.

How do I make it work with anchor tagged parameters?

Comment: I've tested your example on a wiki and works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example should work.

Here's how to do it:

1. Create a page called `Template:tmpl` with contents:

   ```
   [[{{{Target}}}|{{{Name}}}]]
   ```
2. Create a page called `Fruits` with contents:

   ```
   This page lists important fruits.

   == Favorites ==

   * Apple
   * Pear
   * Orange
   ```
3. Edit another page and add:

   ```
   {{tmpl|Target=Fruits|Name=Link to page}}

   {{tmpl|Target=Fruits#Favorites|Name=Link to page with anchor}}
   ```
4. There should now be two links:
   [Link to page](http://www.example.com/Fruits)
   [Link to page with anchor](http://www.example.com/Fruits#Favorites)

Verified to work on a fresh MediaWiki installation.

Comment: This is what I already did, and for some reason is not working

Comment: I double checked that this worked yesterday, by spinning up a new MediaWiki via Docker and trying it there: `docker run --rm -p 80:80 mediawiki` then go to `http://localhost/`

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of MediaWiki? Or maybe your link contains a special character that needs escaping?

Comment: Did try to upgrade it to MediaWiki 1.31.6, still problem. See https://wiki.catglobe.com/RoleExtensionRoleParameter_class and https://wiki.catglobe.com/index.php?title=Template:CGscriptTypeColors_Template&action=edit